# Check property exist in object or not in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, object

I have one problem statement.

**Implement a function propertyExists(obj, path) that takes in an object and a path (string) as arguments and returns ‘False’ if the property doesn’t exist on that object or is null, else returns the value of the property.**

And here is solution.

```
function propertyExists(obj,path) {
    // Write logic here
    let result =  obj.hasOwnProperty(path);
    if(result)
    {
     return (obj.path);       
    }
    else
    {
        return result;        
    }
}
```

Is this correct way of doing it?

Comment: Are you facing any type of issue with this implementation?

Comment: It depends on what the definition of path is, for me a path would be something like..  `header.customer.address.lines[0]`  etc.  But then your have called it `propertyExists`,  so its likely property anyway, so not sure why its not `propertyExists(obj, property)`   You likely want `return obj[path]` too.

Comment: The check seems incomplete based on requirements.  You could be specific here. -> `if (obj[path] === undefined || obj[path] === null) { return false; } else { return obj[path]; }`

Comment: @SifatHaque Yes when I am submitting the solution I am getting wrong answer message

Answer (score 1):

Multiple issues:
the first name of the function should represent what it is doing,
Path as variable name is vague but propertyName as a variable is clear.
what you should do is either:

1. write function called, "getValue" it returns value if exist or null

```js
    function getValue(obj,propertyName) {
            if(!obj) { // if object not exist
           return null;
            }
           return  obj[propertyName];
        }
```

2. write function called, "propertyExists" should return true if exist else false.

```js
   function propertyExists(obj,propertyName) {
        if(!obj) { // if object not exist
       return false;
        }
       return  obj.hasOwnProperty(propertyName);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function propertyExists(obj,path) {
    // Write logic here
    for(i in path){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(path[i]) === true){
            obj = obj[path[i]];
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
   return obj;
}
```

Comment: it may help to understand

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**object->obj,propertyname->path**

```
function propertyExist(obj, path){
           if (obj.hasOwnProperty(path)) return obj[path];
                   else return false;
                      };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here, as far as I can understand, the objects could be nested also.

Let's take obj as {"a":{"b":"dadsa"}} and path as ab

Now, the the solution which you have posted will not work. Ideally, it should return dadsa, but it will return false.

Try the below code, it will work for nested objects also.

```
function propertyExists(obj,path) {
    // Write logic here
    var val=obj;
    for(a of path){
        val=val[a];
        if(!val)
            return false;
    }
    return val;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function propertyExists(obj,path) {
    var val = obj;
    for (a of path) {
     val = val[a];
    if (!val){
      return false;
     }
     return val;
 }
```